# How to build a pascal triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to build a pascal triangle but output is not as expected
i want output as

[image]

```
triangle = []

for i in range(num_rows):
row = [1] * (i + 1)
for j in range(1, i):
row[j] = triangle[i - 1][j - 1] + triangle[i - 1][j]
triangle.append(row)

return triangle

def print_pascals_triangle(triangle):
for row in triangle:
print(" ".join(map(str, row)))

try:
num_rows = int(input("Enter the number of rows for Pascal's Triangle: "))
if num_rows <= 0:
print("Please enter a positive integer.")
else:
pascals_triangle = generate_pascals_triangle(num_rows)
print_pascals_triangle(pascals_triangle)
except ValueError:
print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid integer.")
```

[image: My output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix the code indentation.

Comment: Please provide the expected output as text, not as an image. For instance,  it is not clear how the first 5 could be positioned half below the 1 above it and half not. Or how the first 6 could be exactly centred above the 20 that is 2 rows below it. This is not possible with monospaced output. But there are many such strange positions, so please provide the expected output in text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculation of the triangle is trivial. Output format can be performed with the aid of *str.center()* [ Thanks to @AKX for pointing that out ]

```
def pascal(n: int) -> list:
    r = []

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        row = [c := 1]
        for j in range(1, i):
            row.append(c := c * (i - j) // j)
        r.append(" ".join(map(str, row)))

    return r

if p := pascal(8):
    w = len(p[-1])
    for row in p:
        print(row.center(w))
```

**Output:**

```
         1
        1 1
       1 2 1
      1 3 3 1
     1 4 6 4 1
   1 5 10 10 5 1
 1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
```

Comment: If you produce 2 more rows, then the last row has its first two numbers (1 and 9) to the *left* of their shared "parent" in the previous row. I don't think that is the intention, but the asker has not clarified which output they expect in text format.

Comment: @trincot Just my best effort at making the output look "triangular". If there's a better way please let us know

Comment: I think we need specifications from the asker. It is not clear what they want as output.

Comment: i wanted a output in triangle shape

Comment: @HarshRaj You can help others to help you by being specific about what the output should look like

Comment: i am new to the platform and learning how to use btw thanks for help

Comment: @HarshRaj How does the output from this answer differ from what was expected?

Comment: This could probably be made somewhat shorter using [`str.center()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=center#str.center).